# Palladium Nanocube

Tags: physical-chemistry, metal, materials, transition-metals, nanotechnology

What is the relative permittivity and relative permeability of a palladium nanocube?

If I change the size of this $\ce{Pd}$ nanocube, will these values be changed or remain the same?

Answer (score 1):

For part (1), you should be able to find values on the internet. For (2), relative permittivity and relative permeability are intensive properties and do not change with the size of the system. However, both quantities are functions of the applied electric and/or magnetic fields.

Comment: I'm not so sure - increasing the size of the nanocube may allow higher order plasmon wavefunctions to exist, thus changing the complex dielectric constant. An easier example - it is well known that the color of nanoparticles is dependent on their size.